# Web parts not working when applying new master page

Tags: web-part, master-page

I started a small Sharepoint site as a rush job.  It's a bunch of fairly simple web part pages.  Now that we're expanding it, I need to add a different master page.  I was using our client's master (which I'm not allowed to edit), and I still need to do so, so I created a nested master page from which to inherit.  This works fine in our development environment.  However, when I try to move it to the client's environment, I get the dreaded "one or more web parts on this page reference a zone that does not exist".  Again the pages work without my new master, and they work with my new master in the dev environment, but not in test.  Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I just tried a simplified version of my master page, with the same problem. Shorter code:

```
<%-- _lcid="1033" _version="14.0.4762" _dal="1" --%>
<%-- _LocalBinding --%>
<%@ Master language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Client_PageTitle" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Client_PageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Client_Main" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your new masterpage published/checked in ? If not do it.

Comment: So that wasn't an issue ?